# Length of readline mode string in bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, readline

How do I find the length of readline's mode string (eg `@` or `(cmd)` or `(ins)`)  which is printed in front of the bash prompt? This mode string is activated by [`set show-mode-in-prompt on`](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC10) in `.inputrc`.

I want to determine the length of this string from within `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

I'm trying to do some cursor movement with `tput` inside the prompt to print some info on the terminal's right hand side (so that it can be overwritten if need be), then resume printing the prompt on the left, but I need to take into account the length of the mode string.

Is `$PROMPT_COMMAND` called again and the prompt reprinted if changing mode (e.g) `emacs-mode-string` to `vi-ins-mode-string` as the prefix?

Comment: As a workaround, I believe you can print a screen control code to remember the current cursor position, then pop back to there once you are finished with your digression.  I don't remember the terminology used in `tput` for this, though.

Comment: I found this in [an old answer of mine](//stackoverflow.com/a/7123564/874188): `tput sc` to capture the current cursor position andètput rc` to return back there.

Comment: Or using ANSI CSI codes: `\e[s` and `\e[u`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question regarding mode string length, but a workaround:

I ended up using [ANSI CSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) to save and restore the position of the cursor. (Thanks @tripleee for the pointer).

I was still unable to find the length of the mode string, even when tying to get the cursor position using `PS1=$(getColumn)` where `getColumn` was various things I tried based on:

- [Get vertical cursor position](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88296/get-vertical-cursor-position)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash

My work-around using ANSI CSI codes can be found as [in answer to "Right align part of prompt"](https://superuser.com/a/1203400/365890).

I'm pretty pleased with the work-around as I manged to do it without a single sub-process, and make it `shellcheck`-clean.